# Wix 100% height & width (full screen) iframe

Tags: velo

I would like to display a full screen iframe on Wix showing only the wix header above. This doesn't have to be an iframe, but showing my booking website full screen on the page essentially is what I am after

Happy to use Corvid if there is any options here although it looks like you're restricted to the predefined functions here?

Where do I begin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to set the HTML component in Wix width to 100%. 
Do you want to display content from another site as part of your Wix site? Maybe you can consider using Wix Bookings solution instead?